# How do you catch memory leaks in your iOS projects?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

Memory leaks are frequent problem in iOS projects. A Xcode leaks instrument and a static analyzer don't find all of them. How do you find the leaks?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a place for you to advertise your code - even if your intentions are good natured.

Comment: This post would be better if you frame it as a question, and then [post an answer yourself](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: That's done. After 7 hours I can post my answer.

Comment: @Alexey Thanks for working with the system. :)

Comment: This question has already been asked a lot of times.  You should find an existing question and answer there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help finding memory leaks (general tips)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720418/help-finding-memory-leaks-general-tips)

Comment: No, you are wrong. I understand how memory management works. I have 3 years of a iOS development experience. And I have huge projects and want to find leaks in them. Xcode instruments don't find all leaks. All answers on stackoverflow tell that I should read documentations and use Xcode instruments. Yes that's best advices for beginners. But they don't give any real solution. I gave it below.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed [lib](https://github.com/soniccat/memCheck-for-iOS) which catches leaked objects and visualizes their relationships between each other.

All interactions occur through a Xcode  console. Press pause in a Xcode debugger and input something like that:

```
po [parser run:@"leaks saveGraph /Users/yourName/Documents/dot/mem.txt"]
```

The command generate mem.txt file for a dot tool (http://www.graphviz.org/). A dot must be installed. Then we can convert mem.txt to dot file by;

```
dot -Tdot mem.txt -o mem.dot && open ./mem.dot
```

That will show graph with live and died objects from your application at current moment.  Some examples:

https://github.com/soniccat/memCheck-for-iOS/raw/master/images/pic1.png
https://github.com/soniccat/memCheck-for-iOS/raw/master/images/pic2.png

An arrow from the DetailViewController to the UILabel means that an object of DetailViewController contains an object of UILabel. A dotted arrow shows when an object dead. Live objects have a white background, dead objects have a gray background.

About a parser command format and special filter (fromList) which remove all unnecessary objects you can read on [memCheck-for-iOS git hub page](https://github.com/soniccat/memCheck-for-iOS).

Happy Using :)